# SwiftUI Views with a custom init

Tags: swift, swiftui

Let's say that I am making a custom input element that looks like this:

```swift
struct CustomInput : View {
    @Binding var text: String
    var name: String

    var body: some View {
        TextField(name, text: $text)
            .modifier(InputModifier())

    }
}
```

Currently, when I instantiate this view I'm required to pass both `text` and `name` names to arguments. I want to be able to make the `name` argument optional, like in the example below.

```swift
 CustomInput("Some name", $text)
```

Typically I'd use an init method for this. But I'm not sure how to handle property wrappers like `@Binding` in the init function.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can write your initializer like this:

```swift
struct CustomInput : View {
    @Binding var text: String
    var name: String

    init(_ name: String, _ text: Binding<String>) {
        self.name = name

        // Beta 3
        // self.$text = text

        // Beta 4
        self._text = text
    }

    var body: some View {
        TextField(name, text: $text)
    }
}
```

Comment: Property wrappers changed in beta 4, code updated to reflect that.

Comment: @matt: The $ accesor is now non mutable. When initialising it that way with beta4, the compiler will give you: ***Cannot assign to property: '$text' is immutable***. Note that the dollar sign is still used for passing a binding, the underscore is only necessary when initialising it.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. You haven’t quite described correctly what they did but I am really glad you alerted me to this change! Thanks very much. Here is a summary of the change: https://forums.swift.org/t/se-0258-property-wrappers-third-review/26399