# How to get a Value in a Class before the View begins? | SwiftUI

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui, observedobject

I know wired question, but I dont know how to name the Problem, I am very new to Swift and I am trying to get the @ObservedObject messagesManager(HERE) changed to the ChatId both is coming within a navigation Link, so I have both informations, but I can't merge them before the View starts, and I dont want to have a button to update it, when the View loads, it should change to the new Value. Here the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ChatView: View {
    @State var infos : SessionServiceImpl
    @State var ChatId : String
    
    @ObservedObject var messagesManager = messagingManager(chatID: "")
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            VStack {
                TitleRow(infos: infos)
                    
                ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                    ScrollView{
                        ForEach(messagesManager.messages, id: \.id) { message in
                            MessageBubbleView(infos: infos, message: message)
                        }
                    }
```

When the chatID gets changed it will change the Result in the ForEach. I hope u understand my Problem, because currently it just uses the empty Placeholder.

Comment: Maybe use a init constructor? (Here is the first link found with Google: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56910854/swiftui-views-with-a-custom-init)

Comment: "...when the View loads, it should change to the new Value.", you can also Google `.onAppear`. This is a common practice.